$B(x, r)$ intersecting with $B(x', r')$

Prove that for any real numbers , ′, , ′ with  < ′, 0 < , and 0 < ′,
if  + ′ > ′ −, then (, ) ∩ (′, ′) ≠ ∅.

My proof is as follows:

Let $, ′, , ′ ∈\mathbb R$ with $ < ′, 0 < ,$ and $0 < ′.$ Assume that $ + ′ > ′ − .$
This implies that $x+r>x'-r'.$
Given that $x<x'$ and $r,r'>0,$ the interval $(x-r,x+r)$ does overlap with $(x'-r',x'+r' ).$
Therefore, $(, ) ∩ (′, ′) ≠ ∅.$


My professor is saying that my proof is wrong, but doesn't $x + r > x' - r'$ and $x < x'$ show that the intersection is nonempty?

"the interval (x-r,x+r) does overlap with (x^'-r^',x^'+r^' )" How do you know that? That's basically what you need to prove.

The assumptions show that $x<x'$ and $x+r > x'-r'$. Consider the function $d(t) = (x'-tr')-(x+tr)$. Note that $d(0) > 0$, $d(1) <0$ so there is some $t \in (0,1)$ such that $x+tr=x'+tr'$. Since $x+tr \in B(x,r)$ and $x'+tr' \in B(x',r')$ we have the desired result.

Your proof has a gap: there was no explanation for why $x+r>x′−r′$ implies $(x-r,x+r)$ does overlap with $(x′-r′,x′+r′)$. It relied on intuition instead of rigorous reasoning.
Your comment above precisely means the supremum of $B(x, r)$ is larger than the infimum of $B(x', r')$. The intuition seems to work this time because you are working with intervals but it would fail if $B(x, r)$ and $B(x', r')$ are replaced with non-interval sets. For example
$$
  \sup \left( (0, 1) \cup (3, 4) \right) = 4 > 2 = \inf \left( (2, 3) \cup (4, 5) \right)
$$
On the other hand, since $B(x, r)$ and $B(x', r')$ are open intervals, they don't include their own supremums or infimums. I think you believed that $B(x, r)$ and $B(x', r')$ contain real numbers between the supremum of $B(x, r)$ and the infimum of $B(x', r')$, but again, this is something you had to explicitly explain.

To clarify, you are not saying I am wrong with this justification? but it just doesn't have rigor?
Even though B(x, r) and B(x', r') don't contain the the supremums or infimums, x+r>x'−r' still shows that this doesn't matter

I would not say you were wrong but lacked explanation. Why does $x + r > x' - r'$ imply the two open intervals not overlapping? I mean, if you didn't use any mathematical results to justify your reasoning, then the reasoning is not valid.

While a mathematical proof is informal, it still needs to be convincing or at least persuasive. Your proof is so sketchy that it's a judgement call whether or not it is actually valid. Specifically: it's hard to tell whether your reasoning from line 2 to line 3 involves logical leaps. Even if your reasoning is actually rigorous, this is not evidenced by the level of detail (as required by the reader) being exhibited.
Why not incorporate that final paragraph in the proof? While you're at it, elaborate on how

$x$ has to be to the left of $x'.$

together with

the right endpoint of $B(x, r)$ is bigger than the left endpoint of $B(x', r')

shows that

they must overlap.


Alternative proof:
$r,r'>0\tag1$
$x'>x\tag2$
$r+r'>x'-x\tag3$
From (3): $$-(r+r')\le x-x'.\tag4$$
From (1) and (2): $$x-x'<0<r+r'\\x-x'\le r+r'.\tag5$$
Combining (4) and (5): $$|x-x'|\le r+r'\\(, ) ∩ (′, ′) ≠ ∅,$$ as required.
